Not able to get email when user submits the form
I have created contact form with react and connected it with mysql database hosted using RDS. i used django for building the database. before some days i was able to get email when i am submitting the form and the data was also been stored in the database but now when i am submitting the form i am not getting an email notification of submission but i can see the data in my database. i also tried to send test email from the console and it worked. when i changed the API from urls.py and then i submitted the form, i got the mail but when i did the submission again i did not get any mail.
this is my setting.py code
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME', default='myportfolio'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER', default='root'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD', default=''),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST', default=''),
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT', default='3306'),
    }
}

# Email backend configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD') 





views.py 

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .models import Form
from .serializers import FormSerializer
import json


@csrf_exempt
def formApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            if id:
                form = Form.objects.get(id=id)
                form_serializer = FormSerializer(form)
                return JsonResponse(form_serializer.data, safe=False)
            else:
                forms = Form.objects.all()
                forms_serializer = FormSerializer(forms, many=True)
                return JsonResponse(forms_serializer.data, safe=False)
        except Form.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Form not found'}, status=404)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        form_serializer = FormSerializer(data=form_data)
        if form_serializer.is_valid():
            form_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Added Successfully'}, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(form_serializer.errors, status=400)
    
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        form_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        try:
            form = Form.objects.get(id=id)
            form_serializer = FormSerializer(form, data=form_data)
            if form_serializer.is_valid():
                form_serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Updated Successfully'}, status=200)
            return JsonResponse(form_serializer.errors, status=400)
        except Form.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Form not found'}, status=404)
    
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            form = Form.objects.get(id=id)
            form.delete()
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Deleted Successfully'}, status=204)
        except Form.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Form not found'}, status=404)

@csrf_exempt
def form_submission_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            name = data.get('name')
            email = data.get('email')
            subject = data.get('subject')
            message = data.get('message')

            # Debug prints
            
            # Validate form data
            if not name:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Name is required'}, status=400)
            if not email:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Email is required'}, status=400)
            if not subject:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Subject is required'}, status=400)
            if not message:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Message is required'}, status=400)

            # Save to database
            Form.objects.create(name=name, email=email, subject=subject, message=message)

            # Send email
            send_mail(
                'New Form Submission',
                f'You have a new form submission:\n\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nSubject: {subject}\nMessage: {message}',
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
                fail_silently=False,
            )

            
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Form submitted successfully!'})
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid data'}, status=400)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=405)



check send_mail return value. success value is 1.

you can try #form_submission_view
data = request.POST
email = data['email']

Still not getting the email.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
